# retrieve unique hotel id for users for booking system

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql related problem. I need to write a complex query for the table described below

```
id  date        quantity    roomtypeid  hotelid
```

User will search hotels using check in and check out date and specify numbers of room(quantity) with the search query, so what I need to do is get hotel ids from above table which have minimum  number of rooms available from check in to check out date.

```
1   04-01-2013  3   4   10
2   04-02-2013  3   4   10
3   04-03-2013  3   4   10
4   04-04-2013  3   4   10
5   04-01-2013  3   4   11
6   04-02-2013  3   4   11
7   04-03-2013  3   4   11
8   04-04-2013  3   4   11
9   04-01-2013  3   4   12
10  04-02-2013  3   4   12
```

The resulting query should only give 10,11 as hotel id if user wants to book from 04-01-2013 to 04-03-2013 with 3 rooms.

Regards
Subash

Comment: The question is not really clear. Can you elaborate more or give some more details.

Comment: So what have tried? so your effort.

Comment: room quantity needs to be matched and all the dates in between start and end date must be present in the date column, eg If I book from 2nd to 4th day then rooms must be available for 2,3,4 dates

Comment: There may be three rooms available - but there's no evidence that from one day to the next it's the same three rooms that are available. It would drive me nuts to have to move rooms every day! However, that aside, another way to conceptualize your problem is to look for and then exclude any hotels that have less than the required number of rooms between those dates. A calendar table, holding all relevant dates, may be useful for this.

Comment: i am saying exactly that, only hotels with minimum number of specified rooms within that date must be selected

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE2**

```sql
SELECT `hotelid` 
  FROM table1
 WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-03'
   AND quantity >=3
 GROUP BY `hotelid`
HAVING COUNT(*) = DATEDIFF('2013-04-03', '2013-04-01') + 1
```

*3 in a `WHERE` clause is a number of rooms that should be available.*

Output

```
| HOTELID |
-----------
|      10 |
|      11 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82f0d/4)**

Comment: It doest not work as there can be same dates with different roomtypes id and it messes up with your calculation,

`code`        (1, '2013-04-01', 3, 4, 10),

 (2, '2013-04-03', 3, 4, 10),

 (3, '2013-04-04', 3, 4, 10),

 (4, '2013-04-01', 3, 4, 11),

 (5, '2013-04-02', 3, 4, 11),
 (6, '2013-04-03', 3, 4, 11),
 (7, '2013-04-04', 3, 4, 11),
 (8, '2013-04-01', 3, 4, 12),
 (9, '2013-04-02', 3, 4, 12),
 (10, '2013-04-05', 3, 4, 10),
 (11, '2013-04-02', 3, 6, 10),
 (12, '2013-04-05', 3, 7, 10)`code`

Comment: @Subash If you don't care about roomtypes then don't use it in `GROUP BY`. See updated answer and SQLFiddle

Comment: it still is not working, you are calculating the sum and checking as a whole, not on individual rooms, so if min room quantity is 3 then if a hotel has 1 room for 1 day and 3 rooms for next day then that hotel is passed as valid, which it isn't

Comment: @Subash Updated the answer and sqlfiddle. An additional condition in a `WHERE` clause should take care of it.

Comment: @Subash ... and changed `HAVING` condition to enforce continuity of dates

Comment: I so appreciate your time on this but its still not working and sorry but I kind of forgot to mention one restriction, rooms for each day must be from the same room type, eg If I am in the deluxe room for the first day(id 6) then I should not be moved to a non-deluxe room next day(7) so room type must also be considered. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @Subash That is what was taken into account in my first version of the query. Please provide enough sample data to test this, preferably in a  form of a sqlfiddle or post it in your original question. But probably `GROUP BY hotelid, roomtypeid` will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`hotelid`) FROM `tableName` WHERE `date` = $checkindate AND `date` = $checkoutdate AND `quantity` = $numberofroom
```

Use the above query. it is only dummy query modify it according you(fields name and variable names)